# C GLubyte Array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this problem. I manually initialized the array commented in the code below, and i want a function to do that, it doesnt matter what the values are. I am not able to do that, when i print at the end of the function, everything is 0. Any idea on this?

```
GLubyte *createGraphIndices(int size){


    GLubyte * graphIndices = malloc(size * sizeof(GLubyte));
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (size/2)-1; ++i){ // até
        graphIndices[i] = i;
    }
    for(i = (size/2)-1; i < size-2; ++i){ // até
        graphIndices[i] = i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){ // até
        fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", graphIndices[i]);
    }
    return graphIndices;
}
// GLubyte graphIndices[] = {
// 
//  0,1,
//  1,2,
//  2,3,
//  3,4,
//  4,5,
//  5,6,
//  6,7,
//  7,8,                
//  9,10,
//  10,11,
//  11,12,
//  12,13,
//  13,14,
//  14,15,
//  15,16,
//  16,17
// };
```

Comment: Where do you set a size for the array?  It is not a vector, it doesn't expand dynamically

Comment: malloc does it for me isnt it?

Comment: True, skipped that line ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing them as floats

```
    fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", graphIndices[i]);
```

you should print them as ints

```
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", graphIndices[i]);
```